# When i refresh the page repeating javascript content disapears.how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Im working ticket booking project.when i click on add passenger button it displays name,age and gender option which is by javscript and jquery but when refresh the page this added section disappears.And there is no problem in storing data to database . i dont want that section to disappear when refresh so how can i figure it out?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;

    $('#add').click(function(){
    i++;

  $('#a').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">    <th><input type="text" name="pname[]" placeholder="Name" class="form-control name_list" /></th><th ><input type="number" name="age[]" placeholder="Age" class="form-control name_list" /></th><th scope=""><select class="form-control" id="gender[]" name="gender[]"  placeholder="gender" width=""><option  value="" disabled selected></option> <option>Male</option> <option>Female</option></select></th><th><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></th></tr>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });

});
</script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="No.of Children">Passenger Details</label><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="add" style="margin-left:170px">Add Passenger</button>
            <table class="table table-secondary" id="a" name="a">
            <thead>
            <tr class="table-default">
            <th scope="col-lg-15">
              <? if(isset($pname)): // Name set? ?>
                <? foreach($pname as $item): // Loop through all previous posted items ?>
                  <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'text','name'=>'pname[]','value'=>'','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'pname','placeholder'=>'Name','value'=>set_value('pname[]')]); ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('pname[]'); ?>
                <? endforeach; ?>
              <? else: ?>
              <? endif; ?>
            </th>
            <th scope="col-lg-15">
              <? if(isset($age)): // Name set? ?>
                <? foreach($age as $item): ?>

                 <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'number','name'=>'age[]','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'age','placeholder'=>'Age','value'=>set_value('age[]')]); ?>
              <?php echo form_error('age[]'); ?>
                <? endforeach; ?>
              <? else: ?>
              <? endif; ?>
            </th>
            <th scope="col-lg-15">
              <? if(isset($gender)): // Name set? ?>
                <? foreach($gender as $item): // Loop through all previous posted items ?>
                  <select class="form-control" id="gender[]" name="gender[]"  placeholder="Gender" > 
                    <option>Male</option> 
                    <option>Female</option>
                  </select>
                <? endforeach; ?>
              <? else: ?>
              <? endif; ?>
            </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
```

**controller**

```
   public function reserve_train($train_id)
   {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pname[]', 'Passenger Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('age[]', 'Age', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender[]', 'Gender', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('train_id', 'Train ID', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('origin', 'Origin', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('destination', 'Destination', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('arrivaltime', 'ArrivalTime', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('departuretime', 'DepartureTime', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('class', 'Class', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ano', 'No.of Adults', 'required|max_length[1]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cno', 'No.of Children', 'required|max_length[1]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tamount', 'Total Amount', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cardno', 'Card Number', 'required|min_length[16]|max_length[16]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('noc', 'Name on card', 'required|trim|alpha_numeric_spaces');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('month', 'Month', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Year', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cardtype', 'Card Type', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cvv', 'CVV', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');$data=$this->user_model->fetchdata($this->session->userdata('passenger_id'));
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
       // $data=$this->input->post();
       //if($this->input->post()){
        $pname=implode(", ", $this->input->post('pname[]'));
        $age=implode(", ", $this->input->post('age[]'));
        $gender=implode(",", $this->input->post('gender[]'));
        $data= array(
            'pname[]'=> $pname ,
            'age[]'=>$age ,
            'gender[]'=> $gender,
            'train_id'=>$this->input->post('train_id'),
            'origin'=>$this->input->post('origin'),
            'destination'=>$this->input->post('destination'),
            'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),
            'arrivaltime'=>$this->input->post('arrivaltime'),
            'departuretime'=>$this->input->post('departuretime'),
            'class'=>$this->input->post('class'),
            'price'=>$this->input->post('price'),
            'ano'=>$this->input->post('ano'),
            'cno'=>$this->input->post('cno'),
            'tamount'=>$this->input->post('tamount'),
            'cardno'=>$this->input->post('cardno'),
            'noc'=>$this->input->post('noc'),
            'month'=>$this->input->post('month'),
            'year'=>$this->input->post('year'),
            'cardtype'=>$this->input->post('cardtype'),
            'cvv'=>$this->input->post('cvv'),
        );
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if($this->user_model->reserve($data,$train_id)){

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Train booked successfully');
            return redirect("user/dashboard");
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Failed to Book Train');
              }return redirect("user/reserve/{$train_id}");
    }else{
        $this->reserve($train_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, if you refresh the page, the dynamically added elements WILL disappear because they weren't there in the first place. I don't think you can prevent this. But if you're loading the page after validation fail then you can add additional `GET` parameters and show the contents.

Comment: Please consider implementing a backend for your application.

Comment: how? i tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can keep data on localStorage.

For example: https://scrimba.com/c/cZa6qA6

Comment: i dont know  much about js .so cant write that code?pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store this information either locally in local storage or on the backend via API storage there. Refreshing the page will always destroy dynamically added content.

Comment: Nope, there is no quick win here, it would need to be coded accordingly.